# Create Windows user with LocalService permissions

Tags: windows, user-permissions

Is it possible to create a user account in Windows 7 that has the same permissions as LocalService?

I need this for debugging purposes: I am debugging windows services by running my service as console application.

In the interactive/console mode you can not impersonate such kind of user as LocalService (there are some [tricks](http://geek.hubkey.com/2008/02/impersonating-built-in-service-account.html), but they are unreliable and can be deleted from upcoming releases).

Comment: Would kindly you edit your question to detail which problem[s] you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer this as a purely "technically right" answer. As @jscott eludes to in his comment, your real reasons for wanting this would likely get you a better answer that fits your needs.

Being "LocalService" means having a specific [well-known SID](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330). It's not like being a member of a group. The best you could hope for would be to modify all the ACLs where "LocalService" is named to include the SID of a user or group. That would, effectively, give that user or group the "same permissions" as LocalService. If there are any places in Windows where checks for the LocalService are hard-coded, rather than ACLs, there would be no way to add an equivalent ACE without modifying the code.

Comment: Evan, what do you mean saying "to modify all the ACLs where "LocalService" is named"? Sorry, i'm programmer, not sysadmin. Can you give examples, please?